# Facebook Graph API sharing Link

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to share a link using Facebook Graph API. I am doing following.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Description goes here.",@"description",
                                   @"www.google.com/image.jpg",@"picture",
                                   @"www.google.com/invites/username", @"link",
                                   @"Google",@"name",
                                   @"www.google.com",@"caption",
                                   nil];


    Facebook *fb = [Model shared].facebook;

    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/links" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

and I want the FB Post to be like this:
[image]

But what I 've learned is that Facebook Graph API takes the image and the description by itself from the shared page.

Is there any way to customize the content that you want to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you post [`link`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/) Facebook get OpenGraph tags (like `picture` and `description`) from page located on `URL` you specify as [`link`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/).

Using [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) by publishing [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object instead of [`link`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/) allow you to specify custom info.

Actually to achieve this you can just change `me/links` to `me/feed`:

```
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: But then in that case, the caption (i.e. www.google.com in my case) won't be a link.

Comment: I think there's no way to get the kind of post, the way I want

Comment: @Juicy What is the character limit for name, description,caption etc?